# Disable interaction on upper view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have two views in my program. One is statusView, it's alpha is set to 0.8f. And below it is tableView. How do I disable statusView such way, that clicking on it would not click tableView. Settings `userInteractionEnabled = false;` didn't help.

Here is how i add views.

```
[self.view addSubview:_builded.view]; // obj with my tableView
info = [[Info alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:info.view]; // statusView
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a subview like the following, the tableView underneath would not catch the user interaction.

```
UITableView *testTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
testTableView.delegate = self;
testTableView.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:testTableView];

UIView *statusView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 200)];
statusView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
statusView.alpha = 0.8;
[self.view addSubview:statusView];
```

Comment: Hmm. I'm doing in the same way, yet I still get interaction. See my updated question, on how i add views.

Comment: I have updated my answer. It might be the way you create the views. What is the reason for doing info = [[Info alloc] init]; and then info.view and not create Info as a subclass of UIView?

Comment: `[statusView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]` should really do the trick. And maybe `[testTableView becomeFirstResponder]` helps

Comment: I don't think [statusView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO] would solve anything, since you want the statusView to get the interaction and not the tableView